# How to fix Next.JS' ununderstandable setting of classes

Tags: javascript, next.js

So here I have a little scroller component:

```
export default function Scroller({children, scrollSpeed="10", className, ...props}){


    const period = 1000 / scrollSpeed
    const generated = 'scroller-' + pureGen(10)

    console.log(generated)

    return (
        <>
            <style jsx>
                {`
                .scroller {
                    width: calc(100vw - .5rem) !important;
                    margin-left: calc(-1 * var(--page-padding));
                    overflow-x: scroll;
                    overflow-y: hidden;
                    display: flex;
                    padding: 1rem 0;
                    gap: 2rem;
                    scroll-behavior: auto;
                }

                .scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
                    display: none;
                } 
                `}
            </style>
            <div className={`scroller ${className} ${generated}`} {...props}>
                {children}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

The pureGen() function generated a random ID, which is then console logged.
The value console logged into the browser is: scroller-i934CUja5Y (In a test)
However the real value is: [image]
which is completely different.

What in the world is going on?
I've never seen anything like this before.
I've tried searching for the same problem everywhere but only useless replies appeared.

Comment: The class name is regenerated at every render.

Comment: Yes I know, however, every render then console.logs the value, which turns out to be different to the actual class

Comment: I've also found out that it for some reason changes only before the return statement, after it, it's a completely different value